# How do I unit test a Servlet Filter with jUnit? ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain

Tags: java, junit, mocking, aem, junit4

How to properly cover Filter with JUnit?

```
@SlingFilter(order = -700, scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST)
public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        logger.debug("request for {}, with selector {}", slingRequest
                .getRequestPathInfo().getResourcePath(), slingRequest
                .getRequestPathInfo().getSelectorString());

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code for your testing with `Junit-5`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class LoggingFilterTest{
    
    @InjectMocks
    private LoggingFilter loggingFilter;
    
    @Mock
    private ServletRequest request
    
    @Mock
    private ServletResponse response
    
    @Mock
    private FilterChain filterChain
    
    @Mock
    private RequestPathInfo requestPathInfo;
    
    @Test
    public void testDoFilter() throws IOException, ServletException{
    
        Mockito.when(request.getResourcePath()).thenReturn(requestPathInfo);
        Mockito.when(requestPathInfo.getResourcePath()).thenReturn("/testPath", "selectorString");
        Mockito.doNothing().when(filterChain).doFilter(Mockito.eq(request), Mockito.eq(response));
        
        loggingFilter.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
        
        Mockito.verify(filterChain, times(1)).doFilter(Mockito.eq(request), Mockito.eq(response));
    }
}
```

If you are using `junit4` then change `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Answer (score 3):

Invoke doFilter passing the mock ServletRequest, ServletResponse and FilterChain as its parameters.

```java
@Test
public void testDoFilter() {
    LoggingFilter filterUnderTest = new LoggingFilter();    
    MockFilterChain mockChain = new MockFilterChain();
    MockServletRequest req = new MockServletRequest("/test.jsp");
    MockServletResponse rsp = new MockServletResponse();

    filterUnderTest.doFilter(req, rsp, mockChain);

    assertEquals("/test.jsp",rsp.getLastRedirect());
}
```

In practice, you'll want to move the setup into an `@Before setUp()` method, and write more `@Test` methods to cover every possible execution path.

And you'd probably use a mocking framework like `JMock` or `Mockito` to create mocks, rather than the hypothetical `MockModeService` etc. I've used here.

This is a unit testing approach, as opposed to an integration test. You are only exercising the unit under test (and the test code).

Answer (score 1):

If you use AEM Mocks with Junit5, then it could look something like this.

```
@ExtendWith(AemContextExtension.class)
class SimpleFilterTest {

    private static final AemContext context =  new AemContext(ResourceResolverType.RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK);

    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "/content/test";
    private static final String SELECTOR_STRING = "selectors";

    private static SimpleFilter simpleFilter;
    private static FilterChain filterChain;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        simpleFilter = context.registerService(SimpleFilter.class, new SimpleFilter());
        filterChain = context.registerService(FilterChain.class, new MockFilterChain());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("GIVEN the request, WHEN is executed, THEN request should be filtered and contain corresponding header")
    void testDoFilter() throws ServletException, IOException {
        context.requestPathInfo().setResourcePath(RESOURCE_PATH);
        context.requestPathInfo().setSelectorString(SELECTOR_STRING);

        simpleFilter.doFilter(context.request(), context.response(), filterChain);

        assertEquals("true", context.response().getHeader("filtered"));
    }

}
```

Mock

```
public class MockFilterChain implements FilterChain {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

Some simple filter

```
@Component(service = Filter.class)
@SlingServletFilter(scope = SlingServletFilterScope.REQUEST)
@ServiceRanking(-700)
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        log.debug("request for {}, with selector {}", slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getResourcePath(),
          slingRequest.getRequestPathInfo().getSelectorString());

        final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (SlingHttpServletResponse) response;
        slingResponse.setHeader("filtered", "true");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```